# Converting int to byte

Tags: java, byte, type-conversion

```
int i = 234;
byte b = (byte) i;
System.out.println(b); // -22
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(i2); // 234
```

I was looking at this code and was confused about how they values were stored. The first int is stored as 32 bits (4 bytes). b converts to binary and stores its signed value (8 bits). Does i2 store it as an 8 bit unsigned representation or does it convert it back to 32 bits?

Comment: An `int` is always 32-bits. It doesn't change size because you assigned it a value from a different type.

Comment: Also, your question title asks about "int to byte", but the last sentence of the description implies that you're asking about the reverse. Is the byte-to-int conversion the part that is actually confusing you?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have unsigned primitive types.  All `byte` variables are signed 8-bit values.

Whether or not the most significant bit is interpreted as a sign bit, when you do bit-wise operations all the bits that are present are used by the operator.  To make this concrete, the following are equivalent:

```
i2 = b & 0xFF;
i2 = b & ((byte) -1);
```

Comment: *Java does not have unsigned primitive types* -- not true, there is `char`.

Comment: @arshajii: Perhaps *"not quite true"*. Although `char` is freely convertible with `int`, I would argue that the sense of `char` is *not* that of a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

i2 is declares as an int, so it should be a full 32-bit value.  It will contain the binary AND of b, which in this case is the lower 8 bits and 0xFF.

Answer (score 0):

Things aren't "stored as" an unsigned or signed representation. This is a nitpicky distinction, but it seems to be where you're getting confused. The only difference is how the bits are interpreted. What's happening here is the following:

- `i` stores the value 11101010 (plus some number of higher order bytes). Under Java's convention for integer storage format, this represents the value 234.
- `b` stores the value 11101010, since `int`s are converted to `byte`s by simply truncating them. Under Java's convention for numerical byte storage format, this represents the value -22.
- `i2` stores the value 11101010 (plus some number of higher order bytes), because a bitwise operation was applied to `b` so its bits were directly copied. (Had you written `int i2 = b` or `int i2 = b + 0`, the byte would have been converted to its numerical value -22, and then stored as the `int` representation of -22.